# Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'

Tags: android, gradle

I am using local gradle of version 2.4 and IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3
When I run project from IntelliJ it runs fine but when execute `gradle clean build` command from command line it gives the flowing exception and build fails.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 2051 but got 2050 bytes)
```

Comment: I'd suggest you try using gradle-2.2.1/gradlew because the actually version supported by `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3` seems to be 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an old ques which is not yet answered yet.
I got into same problem, when my jar files could not be read by Android Studio and it gave me the above mentioned error.

Taking lead from the comment by -Mikhail Boyarsky I changed classpath in build.gradle file to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'.
Synced project and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0` version to `2.2.3`, then build it with another exception and then I changed the version back to `2.3.0`.

Not sure how it works, looks like a gradle bug.